# Looking for Microsoft Index Server ASP.NET samples

Tags: asp.net, windows, sharepoint

i am not a programmer, but i can frankenstein code snippets with sufficient proficiency that if, by the grace of a few good souls, i could come across some sample ASP code that acts as a GUI to the ms index server, i could certainly make it work and look good.

if anyone can offer any help, i would do a backflip. but i won't put it on youtube. there's enough faceplant videos out there.

summary: does anyone know where i can find index server asp pages? the more complete, the better. snippets are more than welcome.

btw: io tagged this as sharepoint since this is so similar. some moss admins will certainly be able to lend me a hand!

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean ASP or ASP.Net, and which language if ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

How about some samples from CodeProject? Would that suit your needs? I'm sorry I can't offer any more specific help without knowing more details and what you are trying to do.

> [Microsoft Index Server class for ASP](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/asp/clsTextSearch.aspx) (classic ASP)
>
> [Your free search engine – Microsoft Indexing Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IndexingServer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To talk to an index server catalogue from asp.net you can use an ole db connection object.

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSIDXS;Integrated Security .=;Data Source=" + catalogName);
            cmdQuery = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
```

Where catalogName is the name of the catalog on your machine you are querying. And query is a string containing the index query you are using.

```
 //Get reader 
 rQuery = cmdQuery.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

 //Create dataset and load values from reader into it
 dataQuery = new DataSet("IndexResults");
 dataQuery.Load(rQuery, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, new string[] { "" });

 //Return the first table which will be the results from the query
 results = dataQuery.Tables[0].Copy();
```

Don't forget to dispose of the connection and reader in a finally statement :)

Index query itself is very similar to SQL - you can also set properties in the query to be used as aliases so it is easier to read.